# Is there a way to parent an objects position to another objects position in Nuke, so they move parallel to each other?

Tags: nuke

I want to move an object parallel to another object in Nuke. I managed to get the object to move to the same position as the other one. (Copy link paste absolute.) But I wasn't able to figure out how to move it relative to the other object. Copy link and paste relative did not work.

Comment: What about holding control and drag the position of one node to another?

Comment: @poor control(apple:command) puts it on the exact same position i want it to move relatively with the linked object. Like Object 1: y(0.045) Object 2: y(-0.66). If I move it up the new position would be 1:y(0.40) 2:y(-0.71). Both objects move 5 points down...

Comment: You don't want to have 2 transforms (one of them relative)? I think adding an example to the question would be nice for the community.

Comment: I simply want to objects wo move parallel to each other.

http://mathematicsi.com/wp-content/uploads/Angles-in-parallel-lines-01.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply edit the expression values:

- create a new `Transform Node` by hitting <kbd>T</kbd>
- `drag and drop` the translation values by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> from **original transform node to the new one** (this should create a green line between that nodes)
- right click the `translation curve icon` of the new transform node to open up the `Edit Expressions` Window
- in this window you can do some **math with the existing y or x values** to move the the child node

[image]